# AngularJS UI Router: ui-sref not updating URL in address bar?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui-router

I'm building an AngularJS app and I'm using UI-Router in order to navigate through the app.

The flow of the web app consist in first registering or login, then it takes you to a main grid that has a lot of elements that are being displayed through ng-repeat and when you click in one of them it takes you to a dashboard that displays information of the element that has been clicked and it also successfully changes the path to index.html#!/dashboard/(here goes the name of the element)

This is the html 5 code of that main grid:

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="row" ng-controller="ribtStateServicesController" >

        <div class="col-md-3 ribt_HomeGrid" ng-repeat="estado in estados" >
            <div class="img-ribt_overlay" >
               <a ng-click="doWork(estado.idState)" ui-sref="dashboard({ribtNameState: estado.idState})">
                <img src="{{estado.image}}" class="img-thumbnail">
                <div class="ribt_overlay" ></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

However, in that same dashboard I have a side menu, that has the same elements that were used in the main grid before. So I figured that it would take the same logic to be able to use the params that the UI-Router offer in order to change the URL and the content displayed. But it does nothing.

This is the code in the HTML of the dashboard's side menu:

```html
<div class="col-md-6 nopadding" ng-repeat="estado in estados | filter:busqueda">


                    <md-card md-ink-ripple="#ffffff">
                        <img ng-src="{{estado.nolabel}}" class="md-card-image ribt_estado_side_img" 
                        ui-sref="dashboard({ribtNameState: estado.idState})"
                        
                        alt="Estado" ng-click="doWork(estado.idState); toggleLeft()">
                        <md-card-title class="nopadding">
                            <md-card-title-text>
                                <p class="ribt_card_estado_nombre">{{estado.nombre}}</p>
                            </md-card-title-text>

                            <md-menu>


                                <md-button class="md-icon-button float-right" aria-label="Share" ng-click="$mdMenu.open()">
                                    <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                                </md-button>

                                <md-menu-content width="4" ng-mouseleave="$mdMenu.close()">
                                    <md-menu-item ng-repeat="item in [1, 2, 3]">
                                        <md-button>
                                            Option {{item}}
                                        </md-button>
                                    </md-menu-item>
                                </md-menu-content>

                            </md-menu>

                        </md-card-title>

                    </md-card>




                </div>
```

Heres is the code in my app config:

```js
ribtApp.config(function ($stateProvider,$mdThemingProvider,$locationProvider) {
    
    $stateProvider
    
    .state('login',  {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'ribtComponents/ribtLogin/ribtLogin.html',
        controller: 'ribtLoginController'
    }) 
    
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'ribtComponents/ribtHome/ribtHome.html',
        controller: 'ribtStateServicesController'
    })
    
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard/{ribtNameState}',
        templateUrl: 'ribtComponents/ribtDashboard/ribtDashboard.html',
        controller: 'ribtStateServicesController',
        resolve:{
            ribtNameState: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
                return $stateParams.ribtNameState;
                console.log($stateParams.ribtNameState)
            }]
        }
    });
```

I tried a console log to see if the param was being changed and it is but it does nothing to the URL path. I've tried a lot of code that I've found in stackoverflow but none of them has worked. I would be deeply thankful if you could help me with this.

Comment: Where is your `ui-sref`?

Comment: @lin Sorry about that, I've updated the code changing all the ng-href to a ui-sref, nevertheless it still has the same behaviour described earlier.

Comment: @EnriqueTorres did you ever figured out what was going on, I am running into the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch your `ng-href`s to `ui-sref`s, which is what ui-router uses [to set up links to change states](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/hellosolarsystem). So something like...

```
<div class="col-md-6 nopadding" ng-repeat="estado in estados | filter:busqueda">
[...]
   <a ng-click="doWork(estado.idState)" ng-href="index.html#!/dashboard/{{estado.idState}}">
```

should be something more like...

```
<div class="col-md-6 nopadding" ng-repeat="estado in estados | filter:busqueda">
[...]
   <a ng-click="doWork(estado.idState)" ui-sref="dashboard({ribtNameState: estado.idOrWhatever})">
```

with the caveat that I don't know what doWork is actually doing, so I don't know if that is necessary.

If you need to transition in a controller, you can also inject [$state](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/injectables.html#_state) and use [$state.go(...)](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/state.stateservice.html#go), but most of the time `ui-sref`s can get it handled in my experience.

Comment: Hello @Josh, first of all thanks for looking at my problem. I tried changing the ng-href to ui-sref, yet nothing changes in the url. the function doWork does the following thing but I don't know if it has something to do with my problem:

$scope.doWork = function (p) {
        $scope.idState = p;
        $scope.getIDs();
    }

Comment: $scope.getIDs = function () {
$http({
            url: "http://189.164.191.218:4000/ChartService/ChartService",
            method: "POST",
            data: $.param({
                id: $scope.idState
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
            }
        })
}